# Simple JDialog causing Stack Overflow

Tags: java, swing, stack-overflow

I'm writing a visual application in Netbeans, and came across the need for a dialog box. I decided to copy sections of code from the `AboutBox` that Netbeans provides automatically, only to discover that both of these are causing errors to be thrown!

I cannot seem to hunt down the source of the errors, although both are caused when the dialogs are closed.

For simplicity, since I believe that both bugs are related, here is my `Dialog`. I've omitted the `initComponents()` and main (which is never called) methods for brevity, but the defaultCloseOperation is `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`.

When running I get a stack overflow, which I'll post below.

```
public class AddRecipe extends javax.swing.JDialog {

/** Creates new form AddRecipe */
public AddRecipe(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
}

AddRecipe(java.awt.Frame parent) {
    super(parent);
    initComponents();

}

private void cancelButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    dispose();
}


// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JLabel Serves;
private javax.swing.JButton acceptButton;
private javax.swing.JButton cancelButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JList jList1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
private javax.swing.JTextField nameTextField;
private javax.swing.JTextField servesTextField;
private javax.swing.JTextField timeTextField;
// End of variables declaration

}
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:262)
    at java.beans.Statement.invokeInternal(Statement.java:257)
    at java.beans.Statement.access$000(Statement.java:56)
    at java.beans.Statement$2.run(Statement.java:158)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.beans.Statement.invoke(Statement.java:154)
    at java.beans.Expression.getValue(Expression.java:115)
    at java.beans.Encoder.getValue(Encoder.java:105)
    at java.beans.Encoder.get(Encoder.java:225)
    at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:110)
    at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
    at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
    at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
    at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
    at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
    at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
    at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
    at java.beans.PersistenceDelegate.writeObject(PersistenceDelegate.java:116)
    at java.beans.Encoder.writeObject(Encoder.java:74)
    at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeObject(XMLEncoder.java:274)
    at java.beans.Encoder.writeExpression(Encoder.java:304)
    at java.beans.XMLEncoder.writeExpression(XMLEncoder.java:389)
    at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.doProperty(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:229)
    at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initBean(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:264)
    at java.beans.DefaultPersistenceDelegate.initialize(DefaultPersistenceDelegate.java:408)
```

(Stack trace repeats a few hundred more times).

And for completeness, here is the function that calls the Dialog. Again, this code is modeled off of the default Netbeans behavior, (even though the AboutBox Netbeans provided causes a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`).

```
private void newRecipeItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (addRecipe == null) {
        JFrame mainFrame = RecipesApp.getApplication().getMainFrame();
        addRecipe = new AddRecipe(mainFrame);
        addRecipe.setLocationRelativeTo(mainFrame);
    }
    RecipesApp.getApplication().show(addRecipe);
}
```

Comment: Why there are XML things in the stack trace? Have you tried to run this simple JDialog as a separate little project (not part of big one)?

Comment: Tried running it separately, no luck. XML is used elsewhere in the project, but I have no idea how it got in the stack trace.

Comment: Is there anything in the next few hundred lines of stack trace that starts with something like "at AddRecipe.newRecipeItem...(" ?

Comment: The stack trace contains no references to my code, and the output does not indicate that it's truncating the stack trace at all.

Comment: You should have a no-arg constructor, or provide custom nonsense as described in the tsc article. `XMLEncoder` should cope with cycles by inserting back references. However, if you have a `get` method that copies mutable internal data every time then it will be treated as new objects rather than a back reference (it uses `==` rather than `Object.equals`).

Comment: I just discovered that reverting from the OpenJDK to Sun's (Oracle's?) JDK resolved both this issue, and a related issue with the default about box. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As Ashton K mentions in the comments, this problem can be resolved by moving to the Oracle version of the JDK.  So this problem is an issue with running at least his specific version of OpenJDK.